# Segmentation fault while creating an object

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm having trouble with my C++ code which is compiled successfully but crushes with segmentation fault when executed. The point of the trouble is that I can't really fetch the miscue and I don't understand why can't I narrow it down using gdb.

I'm writing a tutorial OpenGL 4 code. At the beginning I'm trying to create a logical map based on real screen sizes. LogicController class is written in order to transfer real stuff given by OpenGL (and glfw) to algorythms and vica versa.

Here's the code.

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
<...>
const GLFWvidmode* mode = glfwGetVideoMode(monitor);
<...>
LogicController logicController( objects_num, mode->width, mode->height, model_area_percentage, move_speed );
<...>
}
```

, where `objects_num` is `int` given by user, `model_area_percentage` and `move_speed` are hard-coded `const float`.

LogicController constructor uses parameters passed to it to construct a `Map` object which is the logical map:

```
LogicController::LogicController ( const int _objects_num, const int screen_width, const int screen_height, const float model_area_percentage, const float _move_speed ) :
    objects_num ( _objects_num ),
    move_speed ( _move_speed )
{
    float square_area = ((screen_width * screen_height) / 100.0 ) * model_area_percentage;
    float square_side = sqrt(square_area);
    square_sizes = new Size( square_side/screen_width, square_side/screen_height ); 

    width_in_squares = screen_width / square_side - 1;
    height_in_squares = screen_height / square_side - 1;

    std::cout << "Width in squares: " << width_in_squares << " Height in squares: " << height_in_squares << std::endl;
    Map* map = new Map( width_in_squares, height_in_squares, objects_num - 1, 0 );  
    std::cout << "Map is successfully constructed";

    setup_objects( objects_num, map );
}
```

The trouble starts here: there is a "Width in squares" in the output stream but "Map is successfully constructed" is never reached while execution. A crash happens before it.

Here's the `Map` contructor:

```
Map::Map( const int _width, const int _height, const int _enemies_num, const int _obstacles_num ):
    width( _width ),
    height( _height ),
    player_coordinates( 0, _width, 0, _height ),
    enemies_num( _enemies_num ),
    obstacles_num( _obstacles_num )
{
    std::cout << "The very beginning of Map" << std::endl;
    map = new int*[height];
    for( int i = 0; i < height; i++ )
    {
        map[i] = new int[width];
        for( int j = 0; j < width; j++ )
            map[i][j] = 0;
    }
    populate_map( enemies_num, obstacles_num );
    print_map( std::cout );
    std::cout << "The very end of Map contructor" << std::endl;
}

void Map::print_map( std::ostream& out_stream )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < height; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < width; j++ )
            out_stream << map[i][j] << " ";
        out_stream << std::endl;
    }
}
```

These code prints the map the way it must print it, and "The very end of Map constructor" is also `std::cout`-ed.
Then, as I understand, the execution must return to `std::cout` after `map` object creation but it doen't, a segmentation fault happens. So the object is not created for some reason. Did I mess up pointers somehow?

Here's how I compile the code:

```
g++ main.cpp Map.cpp LogicController.cpp utilities.cpp game_objects.cpp ShadersHandler.cpp -o main -lGL -lglfw -lGLEW -std=c++11 -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

While compilation nothing is prompted. So what baffles me even more: when I'm trying to use gdb and run the code it cruses: `[Inferior 1 (process 733) exited with code 0377]` even with breakpoints set. Do I use it miscorrectly?

Sorry for large code snippets but I'm not even sure what snippets are necessary here to analyze. I would be grateful for any hint.

Comment: There is no `<< std::endl` at the end of `std::cout << "Map is successfully constructed"`, so the output buffer won't be flushed. Try that and see what happens!

Comment: +1 for explaining the details...

Comment: @AStupidNoob Gosh, I didn't even know about this buffer flushing thing. Now this message is `cout`-ed meaning that the mistake is somplace else in code. I thank you. But still, the gdb part of the question is up - I still don't get it why can't I narrow it down with gdb and what is the error gdb shows.

Comment: Oh, tell me about it. When I found out, I was furious at the amount of time it made me waste! As for the GDB issue: If I were you, I'd make use of Eclipse CDT for development in C++. Using GDB with it is a breeze, you just click "Debug", and you get a great interface that is easy to use. Because of this, I'm not particularly proficient with using gdb on the command line. Perhaps someone more experienced can give some assistance. Anyways, I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Try catch throw in gdb that stops once an exception is thrown. Maybe there is an faulty memory allocation? Try valgrind --tool=cachegrind

Comment: Or you could just call cout.flush();

Comment: are you sure mode != nullptr ?

Answer (score 1):

About the gdb - use it via command-line. the syntax is:

```
gdb {EXECUTABLE} {CORE_FILE}
```

Then, the gdb will load the core file. Afterwards, in case that your program is single-threaded, insert `bt` (bt = back-trace, I guess) and you'll see your process's last-moments...
If your program is multi-threaded, insert `thread apply all bt` to see them all.
To quit gdb, use `q`.